# Shortening Execution Time for a CCH graph

Tags: python-3.x, performance, numpy, matplotlib, numba

I'm trying to reduce the time it takes to graph the following function:

```
def cch(tau):
    return np.sum(abs(-1*np.diff(cartprod)-tau)<0.001)
```

where "cartprod" is short for:

```
cartprod = np.asarray(list(itertools.product(times1,times2)))
```

times1 and times2 are lists whose elements spread out at most 0.25-ish from about 0.0123 to about 99.9948. There are about 5000 of elements per list, also. If you're coming from a neuroscience background, these are spike times. NOTE: this information is redundant to the problem, but just for those who are curious.

I graph it with the following plotting stuff:

```
t = np.linspace(-0.25,0.25,1250) 
vfunc = np.vectorize(cch)
y = vfunc(t)
plt.plot(t,y,'g')
```

plotting this takes about 4 mins. I'm not too concerned about the plotting time (as long as its reasonable: say within 5-10 mins). What I am concerned with is the fact that I will have to graph the average over 10,000 of these functions and I need to be able to do this fast. Is there a way to speed up every call to the function via numba, or any algorithmic enhancement?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try implementing my answer?

Comment: So... How much improvement did you achieve with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your code with using `np.vectorize`, since the shapes of `t` with `(1250,)` and `cartprod` with `(25000000, 2)` (I assumed this from the length of your lists `times1` and `times2`) do not match.

Furthermore unluckily the `numpy` functions needed to speed this up are not yet implemented in `numba`. But still rewriting your code in `numpy` yields a significantly improved speed. On my computer the calculation of `cartprod` can easily be sped up by a factor of around 25.

```
def cartprod(arr_times1, arr_times2):
    res = np.empty((arr_times1.size * arr_times2.size, 2))
    res[:, 0] = np.repeat(arr_times1, arr_times2.size)
    res[:, 1] = np.tile(arr_times2, arr_times1.size)
    return res
def cartprod_iter(times1, times2):
    return np.asarray(list(itertools.product(times1, times2)))

arr_times1 = np.random.rand(5000)
arr_times2 = np.random.rand(5000)
times1 = list(arr_times1)
times2 = list(arr_times2)

%timeit cartprod_iter(times1, times2)
%timeit cartprod(arr_times1, arr_times1)
# 12.9 s ± 954 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
# 521 ms ± 53.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
print(np.all(cartprod(arr_times1, arr_times1) == cartprod_iter(times1, times2)))
# Out: True
```

Now for the `cch` function:
`np.tile` and `np.repeat` can't be numba jitted. If you want to `jit` `cch` you will need to rewrite them by hand. Or you can `jit` some parts of the `cch` function:

```
import numba as nb
@nb.njit
def cch_core(cp, tau):
    return np.sum(np.abs(-1 * np.diff(cp) - tau) < 0.001)

def cch_nb(arr_times1, arr_times2, tau):
    cp = cartprod(arr_times1, arr_times2)
    return cch_core(cp, tau)

def cch(arr_times1, arr_times2, tau):
    return np.sum(np.abs(-1 * np.diff(cartprod(arr_times1, arr_times2)) - tau) < 0.001)

tau2 = np.linspace(-0.25, 0.25, 50)

%timeit cch_nb(arr_times1, arr_times2, tau2)
#2.81 s ± 144 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit cch(arr_times1, arr_times2, tau2)
#15.2 s ± 494 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
print(cch_nb(arr_times1, arr_times2, tau2) == cch(arr_times1, arr_times2, tau2))
# Out: True
```

This is another speed up of a factor 5.4. I used a reduced sice of `tau` to make timings possible. Furthermore a `tau` of shape `(1250,)` will produce a memory error without numba, but will work with numba!

If you want more speed, you need to implement `itertools.product` in numba on your own.
If this code is not working correctly: Please consider that the code you posted in your question can't be reproduced. Posting a fully working minimal example might help.